# ASP.NET customErrors not catching special characters

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to redirect bad urls to custom error page. I am having issues with html tags in the url like

Example -`www.test.com/xyz.aspx?status=500&error=<iframe>`

In above example it's would not show custom error page but *Server Error in '/' Application* a **Runtime Error**

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/defaultError.aspx">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" requestValidationMode="2.0" />` did the trick for me. It's working now.